# How do i return a powerpoint (.pptx) file from REST response in springMVC

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am generating a powerpoint file(.pptx) and i would like to return back this file when a REST call happens. But now am able to get only .File type extension.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ImageManagerPpt/{accessionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/ppt")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> createPptforAccessionId(@PathVariable("accessionId") String accessionId,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException** {
      System.out.println("Creating PPT for Patient Details with id " + accessionId);
      File pptFile = imageManagerService.getPptForAccessionId(accessionId);
      if (pptFile == null) {
          System.out.println("Patient Id with id " + accessionId + " not found");
          return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      }
      InputStream stream = null;
      try {
          stream = new FileInputStream(pptFile);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      ClassPathResource classpathfile = new ClassPathResource("Titlelayout3.pptx");
      InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(stream);

      return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(classpathfile.contentLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(classpathfile.getInputStream()));
}
```

-Bharat

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, this?

```
InputStream stream = new InputStream(pptFile);   
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
response.flushBuffer();
```

You will get file as you put into the InputStream.